# Unable to get data from database when relation is involved

Tags: php, mysql, angular, laravel

I am working on a project that’s been using Angular & Laravel. I have created an API (http://localhost:8000/manpower/get) which has a relation with project table. Now, if I just use:

`Manpower::all()`

or any other query that does not involve relation it will run fine.

But, if I do like:

`Manpower::with(‘getProject’)->get();`

It will throw an error.

I am not sure what’s the issue here.

This is my Angular Code:

```
this._http.get(this.apiURL+'/manpower/get', {headers}).subscribe(
    (result: any) => {
        console.log(result)
    },
    error => console.log(error)
)
```

This is my Laravel route:

```
Route::get('/manpower/get', [App\Http\Controllers\ManpowerController::class, 'get'])->middleware('auth:api');
```

This is my controller:

```
public function get(){
    $power =  Manpower::with('getProject')->get();
    dd($power);
    // return Manpower::with('getProject')->get();
}
```

This is my Manpower model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'project_id',
    'company',
    'type',
    'user_id'
];

public function getProject(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Project::class,'id','project');
}
```

This is my Project Model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'job',
    'title',
    'location',
    'department_id',
    'client',
    'assigned_manager',
    'active',
    'user_id'
];

public function getManpower(){
    return $this->hasMany(Manpower::class);
}
```

Now, the error which I got depends on my handler:

This is the function in my handler.php:

```
public function register()
{
    // $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
    //     //
    // });

    $this->renderable(function (Exception $e, $request) {
        return response()->view('errors.invalid-order', [], 500);
        //return response()->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()], $e->getCode() ?: 400);
    });
}
```

If I return this:

`return response()->view('errors.invalid-order', [], 500);`

it gives the following error:

```
{,…}
exception: "Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError"
file: "C:\\Users\\Maisum Abbas\\qhse\\qhse-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\FileViewFinder.php"
line: 137
message: "Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: View [errors.invalid-order] not found. in C:\\Users\\Maisum Abbas\\qhse\\qhse-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\FileViewFinder.php:137\nStack trace:\n#0 C:\\Users\\Maisum Abbas\\qhse\\qhse-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\FileViewFinder.php(79): Illuminate\\View\\FileViewFinder->findInPaths('errors.invalid-...', Array)\n#1 C:\\Users\\Maisum Abbas\\qhse\\qhse-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Factory.php(138): Illuminate\\View\\FileViewFinder->find('errors.invalid-...')\n#2 C:\\Users\\Maisum Abbas\\qhse\\qhse-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ResponseFactory.php(85): Illuminate\\View\\Factory->make('errors.invalid-...', Array)\n#3 C:\\Users\\Maisum Abbas\\qhse\\qhse-backend\\app\\Exceptions\\Handler.php(43): Illuminate\\Routing\\ResponseFactory->view('errors.invalid-...', Array, 500)\n#4 C:\\Users\\Maisum Abbas\\qhse\\qhse-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php(336): App\\Exceptions\\Handler->App\\”
trace: []
```

And if I return this:

`return response()->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()], $e->getCode() ?: 400);`

It gives the following error:

`{error: "A non well formed numeric value encountered"}`

Please help.

Comment: Project::with(‘getProject’)->get(); try using quotation marks not backticks

Comment: I tried "" and '' both but still facing the error. @Amir

Comment: Did you try this? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#customizing-the-pivot-attribute-name

Comment: I just tried. Didn't work. Can you please provide an example of how to do it? May be I didn't do it right. @Mochilo

Comment: According to the link, you need to define an alias for the relationship:
`return $this->belongsTo(Project::class,'id','project')->as('project');`
Didn't try it, though.

Comment: I have tried it but it gives ```error: "Call to undefined relationship [getProject] on model [App\\Models\\Manpower]."``` @Mochilo

Comment: Just guessing: after defining the alias, try `Manpower::with('project')->get();`. If that doesn't work either, I'm afraid you'll need someone with more recent experience in Laravel than me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your manpower model:

```
 public function getProject()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Project', 'project_id', 'project_id');
    }
```

If this doesn't work then try changing you function name to project instead of getProject